# Picklist value should get update in the short form by trigger

Tags: trigger

object1_c contain Type__c field this is Picklist data type and s picklist field (picklist values "New Customer-New Order,Existing Customer- New Order,
Existing Customer- Order Renewal")
object2_c contain Type__c field this is Picklist datatype

Here i want to update the object2_c Type__c field with the picklist values of object1_c Type__c with the short form of picklist values

```
"New Customer-New Order =NN"

"Existing Customer- New Order=EN"

"Existing Customer- Order Renewal=ER"
```

can any one help me....

Comment: You can create picklist values as NN, EN and ER in Type__c picklist field in object2__c and update this field whenever Type__c field in object1__c is changed using Process Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the custom `object2__c` and edit the values for the `Type__c` picklist to match those for custom `object1__c` `Type__c's` picklist. You should find an option to replace values when you get to the menu and edit the field.